# How to use FIR with Kaiser windows for 2D image

Tags: image-processing, filters, finite-impulse-response

I am trying to use FIR filter (opensource codes from iowa hills software) as low pass filter, kaiser window, to filter 2D image.

Does someone can guide me that how can I do that? I am able to obtain FIRCoeff() as filter coefficients. Not sure how to use it on a 2D image.

My goal is to filter high-frequency noise in my 2D image.

Thanks.

Comment: Which platform will you implement the filtering in? Or do you just need a theoretical answer ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_dimensional_window_design#2-D_Window_Functions